# How to use defvar with the symbol name in another variable?

Tags: symbols, defvar

I am trying to create a global variable which name is contained in another variable, using `defvar`:

```
(let ((var-name "my-test-var"))
  ;;(defvar (intern var-name) "some value")
  (defvar (make-symbol var-name) "some value"))
```

This gives error:

```
(wrong-type-argument symbolp (make-symbol var-name))
```

The following seems to work

```
(let ((var-name "my-test-var"))
  (let ((var-sym (intern var-name)))
    (setf (symbol-value var-sym) "some value")))
```

but is it equivalent to using `defvar`, and how can I add the doc string as in `defvar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't equivalent.  If you test the symbol of a `defvar`'d variable with `special-variable-p` you get `t`, however this is not the case for your code.  This bit must be set for the variable to be usable with dynamic binding.  There doesn't appear to be a way to set this bit, other than by using special forms like `defvar`, `defalias` or the `defcustom` macro (which expands into `defvar`).

The standard solution is to use a macro for programmatically defining variables with generated names:

```
(defmacro my-defvar (name &optional value docstring)
  (let ((symbol (intern name)))
    `(defvar ,symbol ,value ,docstring)))

(my-defvar "foo" 1)
foo ;=> 1
(special-variable-p 'foo) ;=> t
```